# Changing pitch in an iOS audio player—like Alvin and the Chipmunks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, core-audio

I found this code fragment in StackOverflow.  I think this is what I want to use.  But I cannot get it to change the pitch—as I expected it to.  I figured changing the 44100.0 up/down would affect the pitch.  But I'm getting no change, regardless of the setValue.

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
[settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRate];
```

Clearly I'm missing something.

Any additional fragments available to give this some more context?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458065/iphone-voice-changer

Comment: Check this tutorial:
http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/47 The tutorial shows how to create application that will record audio and play modified audio. It also shows how to add parameters so user will be able to change modified audio by slowing it down or by increasing its speed.

Comment: User wasn't asking for a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Quoting answers from the related question.

> There is a [Time-Pitch Stretch Tutorial](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/)
>   on the DSP Dimensions site.

and...

> Take a look at [Dirac](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html). It’s free of charge, though not free software.