# iPhone voice changer

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am developing an iphone app, which records user voice and change it into a female voice
like (TALKING TOM and iHOBO). I am new to audio manipulation. 
Please tell me which api is required to do this? 
Can i implement this feature using iphone sdk apis?
Is there any open source to implement this feature?
Is there any tutorial regrading this?

Thanks in Advace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no built-in iOS APIs that will do independent time-pitch modification.

There is open source code that implements time-pitch stretching in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), but I don't know whether this code has been ported to iOS.  Same with [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/).

There is a T[ime-Pitch Stretch Tutorial](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/) on the DSP Dimensions site.

Update: In late 2012, the kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch Audio Unit was included with and built into the release of iOS 6, so you can now implement (independant time-pitch modification) voice changing using iOS APIs. See Apple's [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/kaudiounitsubtype_newtimepitch) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Dirac](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html). It’s free of charge, though not free software.

Answer (score 4):

the great link to download the sample code that provides all your needs,[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?dofz0hofjrlkrg9) also refer [here](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app) for gaining more knowledge regarding your question.

In the init method of the Sample Code of HelloWorldLayer.mm ,u can see three float values as

```
time      = 0.7;  
pitch     = 0.8;
formant   = pow(2., 0./12.);
```

just adjust the pitch value to 1.9,it would be really a nice cat sound!!!

Comment: but it only captures voice for few seconds what if user speaks for countinuous 15 seconds.......or more

Comment: @aloksinha Define your values to #define AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD 0.01
#define MAX_SILENCETIME 0.8 and remove "[audioMonitor stop]" in the "if (audioMonitorResults > AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD)" loop on "-(void) monitorAudioController: (ccTime) dt" method...It will work...:)now u can record for a long time n play it..

Comment: thanks for your responce.i m testing this .then i will tell you!

Comment: thanks it works,but plz can u explain me why ou removed "[audioMonitor stop]" in the "if (audioMonitorResults > AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD)" loop on "-(void) monitorAudioController: (ccTime) dt" method..,thanks

Comment: [audiomonitor stop] is the reason for the short record.After start recording the audio in the 'if' loop,[audiomonitor stop]quits the recording and play it.So only the recorded clip is too short.[audiomonitor stop] method takes a few seconds to proceed,that few seconds is your short time of the recorded sound clip.Hope you understand.;)@aloksinha

Comment: Thanks very much.....:) it is the best help i  have ever got on stackoverflow...... awesome thanks,

Comment: plz tell me one more think how it works  formant = pow(2., 0./12.); .....thanks in advance.....:)@balan prabhu

Answer (score 0):

Some great sound mangling SDKs from http://LittleEndian.com/Developers/ should help.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?