# Talking Tom Cat Clone App

Tags: iphone, signal-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone voice changer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458065/iphone-voice-changer)

I want to make an applications similar to Talking Tom Cat, But i am not able to identify the approach for sound.

How I can convert my sound into cat sound?

Answer (score 4):

Look up independent time pitch stretching of audio.  It's a digital signal processing technique.  One method that can be used is the phase vocoder technique of sound analysis/resynthesis in conjunction with resampling.  There seem to be a couple companies selling libraries to do suitable time pitch modification.

Answer (score 2):

The technique to convert a normal voice into a squeaky voice is called time-scale modification of speech. One way is to take the speech and reduce the pitch by a certain amount. Another approach is to stretch/compress the speech so that the frequencies in the voice get scaled by an appropriate amount. These are techniques in digital signal processing.

Answer (score 0):

the great link to download the sample code that provides all your needs,[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?dofz0hofjrlkrg9) also refer [here](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app) for gaining more knowledge regarding your question.

In the init method of the  Sample Code of HelloWorldLayer.mm ,u can see three float values as

```
time      = 0.7;  
    pitch     = 0.8;
    formant   = pow(2., 0./12.);
```

just adjust the pitch value to 1.9,it would be really a nice cat sound!!!