# How can I reduce the speed of sound playing on Iphone using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, signal-processing, core-audio, openal

I have an mp3 that I want to play slowly without altering the pitch. Is there a way to do it? I can convert into other forms, if I can do it in other forms. This is for a iPhone app that I am developing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A time-pitch modification/stretching algorithm or library could be used for this.  You could develop some DSP analysis/resynthesis code for a [phase vocoder](http://music.dartmouth.edu/~book/MATCpages/chap.5/5.4.pvoc.html), a [PSOLA pitch corrector](http://cnx.org/content/m33242/latest/), or use a commecial library such as [Dirac](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac/).

See the stackoverflow question: [iPhone voice changer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458065/iphone-voice-changer) for some other answers to a similar question.